# Program hangs after reallocating into char**

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am trying to read lines until EOF. If the line is longer than maxLength, the rest gets truncated.
If the number of rows exceed S, it should reallocate for double the amount.
Everything works well until the reallocation. When it gets to that part, the program crashes.
I have been sitting on this for 2 days.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define S 8

char ** readLines(int * wordCountp, int maxLength) {
  char line[maxLength + 1];
  int size = S;
  char ** words = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
  if (words == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  int i = 0;
  while (fscanf(stdin, "%s", line) == 1) {
    words[i] = malloc((maxLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(words[i], line, maxLength);
    i++;
    if (i == size) {
      size *= 2;
      words = realloc(words, size * sizeof(char));
      if (words == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    if (words == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    free(words[i]);
  }
  words[i] = NULL;
  *wordCountp = i;
  return words;
}
```

Allocating with `sizeof(char*)` instead of `sizeof(char)` messes up the array, but still doesn't solve the problem.

Creating a separate `char**`, reallocating that one and then copying the original into that does not work either.

Comment: is there a  reason you're doing `free(words[i]);` at the end of each iteration?

Comment: You **must** use `sizeof(char*)` for the very first `malloc` and the `realloc` (the `malloc inside the loop is correctly using `sizeof(char)`).

Comment: What @AdrianMole said.  A good way to avoid silly errors like this is to deref the allocated pointer as the arg to `sizeof`: `char ** words = malloc(size * sizeof *words);`. Same with `realloc`.

Comment: @Gene Agreed.  Further: although `size * sizeof *words` is same as `sizeof *words * size`, leading with `sizeof *words` insures the multiplication is done using `size_t` math in more complex cases.  Makes a difference with `int i, j; ... sizeof *words * i * j` and `i * j` may overflow `int` math, but not `size_t` math.

Comment: Yeah, in this example it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

**Avoid allocation size mistakes**

Allocate to the size of the referenced object, rather than the size of the type, which was wrong here.

```
//                               v----------v  Wrong type and too small 
// char ** words = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
char ** words = malloc(sizeof words[0] * size);
//                     ^-------------^ Just right  

// words = realloc(words, size * sizeof(char));
words = realloc(words, sizeof words[0] * size);
```

**Copy the whole string**

```
words[i] = malloc((maxLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
//                         v-------v  1 too short
// strncpy(words[i], line, maxLength);
strcpy(words[i], line);
```

**Use `fgets()` to read a *line***

`fscanf(stdin, "%s", line)` will not read a *line*, more like it will read a *word*.  Without a *width*, buffer overflow possible.

```
// fscanf(stdin, "%s", line)
while (fgets(line, sizeof  line, stdin)) {
```

Comment: Thank you, changing the type worked! While buffer overflow wasn't a concern here, I realized that fscanf has lots of unexpected behavior in this particular use case.

Comment: @user20946097 I hope your code did not change from one type to another type.  Instead to `sizeof words[0] * size`.